# Socket IO and postgresql hangups in while loop

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Tech stack

**Frontend:** VueJS
**Backend:** Flask Python3

**Issue:**

I am using VueJS on the front end utilizing the socket io client library that when a button is clicked it emits an event on the socket connected to my backend.

Once the event is emitted and received on the backend the code enters a method that has a while true loop and is broken out of the loop when there is a certain value present in the DB; until that point ( 20 minutes, 4 hours ) it stays in this loops and checks the status state every few seconds.

The error I am receiving ( see below ) is due to too many connected clients which I dont get because the control exits the code that performs the query and the stack should be clear ( postgres client connection closed ) the fact that the query is in a with statement makes me says this, but obviously it's not.

My question is - how do I return the client? and allow this to do the same task without the error and more efficiently?

ERROR:

```
File "/home/kidcode/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/application-backend-p56sp5Ck-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

CODE

*filename(io.py)*

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
socketio = SocketIO(cors_allowed_origins="*")
```

*filename(socket_listener.py)*

```
    from ..io import socketio
    from flask_socketio import emit, disconnect
     
     
    @socketio.on("connect")
    def test_connect():
       emit("after connect", {"data": "Client has connected!"})
     
     
    @socketio.on("system_started")
    def test_broadcast_message(message):
       socketio.start_background_task(target=SystemMonitorHandler(socketio))
     
     
    @socketio.on("disconnect_request", namespace="/test")
    def disconnect_request():
       @copy_current_request_context
       def can_disconnect():
           disconnect()
```

*filename(system_monitor.py)*

```
class SystemMonitorHandler:
    def __init__(self, socketio):
        socketio = socket.io
        self.monitor_system_status()

def monitor_system_progress(self) -> None:
       """[summary]"""
       # TODO use values from the query to break this loop
       while True:
           self.socketio.sleep(2)
           _system_queries: object = SystemQueries()
           _system_status: dict = (
               _data_migration_history.get_system_job_status(system_id=1, uuid=2)
           )
           self.socketio.emit("message", {"data": status})



   def get_system_job_status(self, system_id: str, uuid: str) -> dict:

       _system_job_schema: object = SystemJobSchema(many=True)
       try:
           with SqlAlchemyUnitOfWork(
               session=request_session_factory, files=SystemJobRepository
           ) as uow:
               return _system_job_schema.dump(
                   uow.repositories.files.filter(
                       system_id=system_id, requested_by=uuid
                   )
                   .with_entities(
                       SystemModel.system_status,
                       SystemModel.job_end_date,
                       SystemModel.job_start_date,
                   )
                   .all()
               )
       except (DatabaseTransactionError, DatabaseSessionError) as err:
           self.logger.exception(
               ConsoleColourHelper.FAIL
               + "Unable to fetch requested resource from database : \
                   {}".format(
                   err
               )
           )




import abc
from functools import cached_property
from types import SimpleNamespace
from typing import Any, Callable, Iterable, Union
 
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from types import SimpleNamespace
 
 
class AbstractUnitOfWork(abc.ABC):
   repositories: SimpleNamespace
 
   def __enter__(self) -> "AbstractUnitOfWork":
       return self
 
   def __exit__(self, *args):
       pass
 
   @abc.abstractmethod
   def commit(self):
       raise NotImplementedError
 
   @abc.abstractmethod
   def rollback(self):
       raise NotImplementedError
 
 
 
 
============= separate file START ==========================
 
class AbstractRepository(abc.ABC):
   @abc.abstractmethod
   def filter(self, **kwargs) -> Iterable[Any]:
       raise NotImplementedError
 
   @abc.abstractmethod
   def save(self, model: Any):
       raise NotImplementedError
 
   @abc.abstractmethod
   def get(self, id_: Any) -> Any:
       raise NotImplementedError
 
 
class SQLAlchemyAbstractRepository(AbstractRepository, abc.ABC):
   model = Any
 
   def __init__(self, session: Session):
       self.session = session
 
   def filter(self, **kwargs):
       return self.session.query(self.model).filter_by(**kwargs)
 
   def save(self, model):
       self.session.add(model)
       self.session.flush()
 
   def get(self, id_):
       return self.session.get(id_)
 
   def delete(self):
       # TODO
       pass
 
 
class SqlAlchemyUnitOfWork(AbstractUnitOfWork):
   def __init__(
       self,
       session=Union[Callable[[], Session], Session],
       **kwargs: SQLAlchemyAbstractRepository
   ):
       self._session = session
       self._repository_config = kwargs
 
   @cached_property
   def session(self):
       return self._session() if callable(self._session) else self._session
 
 
 
 
   def __enter__(self) -> AbstractUnitOfWork:
       repositories = {
           name: repository(self.session)
           for name, repository in self._repository_config.items()
       }
       self.repositories = SimpleNamespace(**repositories)
       return super().__enter__()
 
   def __exit__(self, *args):
       self.session.close()
 
   def commit(self):
       self.session.commit()
 
   def rollback(self):
       self.session.rollback()
 
========== separate file END ==========================
```

Comment: What is `SqlAlchemyUnitOfWork` and how is it implemented?

Comment: @Miguel thanks for the response I have added the requested info in the above snippet. PS see you're quite active on other forums thanks for your contributions :)